# Laravel отложенный запрос в базу

Tags: laravel, транзакции

Требуется реализовать такую ситуацию:
В один метод контролера по одному роуту приходит набор данных по которым нужно собрать несколько sql запросов. 
В другой метод (или даже в метод другого контроллера)  приходит информация о том, коммитить эти запросы или откатить.
Пробовал в одном методе запускать beginTransaction а в другом commit, но во втором классе создается новый объект DB, который понятия не имеет, что где-то была запущена транзакция. 
Значит скорее всего нужно создать этот объект глобально. Попробовал так в сервис провайдере:

```
$this->app->singleton('Conn', function () {
//так            return new \DB;
//и так            return new Connection(\DB::connection()->getPdo());

});
```

но все равно при вызове `\App::make('Conn');` класс пересоздается по новому. 
Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: зачем вам комитить в другом контроллере?

Comment: Ну, необязательно  в другом. Можно и в этом же, но в другом методе, который вызывается по другому роуту

Comment: Как мне сказал один очень уважаемый человек, синглтон просто обещает нам, что будет существовать только один объект класса, но его свойства не сохраняются, вроде как-то так..

Comment: Суть в том, что каждый запрос - это новый экземпляр приложения.

Comment: Хорошо, есть ли другие способы создания глобального класса, не через singleton? Или может быть в данной ситуации, есть более простое решение?

Comment: мне кажется надо смотреть в сторону очереди и кеша

Comment: хотя можно проще. ты собираешь нужные данные в сессию, а когда надо сделать действие - вытаскиваешь из сессии нужные данные. Сессия - прекрасное место для передачи состояния приложения между запросами

Comment: А еще вместо сессии (которая будет жрать ОЗУ) лучше использовать "временные" таблицы в БД, которые будут работать как промежуточное хранилище.

Comment: Ну про ОЗУ - это если сессия в редисе, если в файлах, ОЗУ не расходуется.

Comment: У меня вопрос: а если нужно хранить состояние объекта, то что лучше использовать?

Comment: Если объект является уникальным для каждого посетителя - сессии. Любые  труктуры данных будут сериализованы и сохранены в хранилище (настраивается в `config/session.php`) Могут быть redis, mysql, file, etc..

Comment: Повторюсь еще раз - ЛЮБЫЕ струтуры данных ты можешь сохранить в сессии под своим ключем. Пока не лезь во вложенные ключи. используй простой ключ сессии, например `session_key`. И сделай пример, который я тебе написал в ответе на вопрос. Просто сделай и поиграйся с данными, сохраняемыми в сессию.

Comment: @МаксимК, да я не автор вопроса, так спросил между прочем:))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на примере роутов (сможешь адаптировать под контроллеры)

```
Route::get('/test1', function(Request $request){
    $request->session()->put('session_key', $request->data);
    $request->session()->save(); //сохранить надо
});

Route::get('/test2', function(Request $request){
    $sessionData = $request->session()->get("session_key", 'defaultValue(mixed)');
    // Действия с данными из предыдущего запроса.
    dump($sessionData);
});
```

Инфа по сессиям http://laravel.su/docs/5.4/session

Comment: Спасибо. А есть вариант запихнуть в сессию объект Connection в котором запустили транзакцию, потом извлечь ее и выполнить коммит. Твой вариант неплох, но хотелось бы попробовать отложенный коммит транзакции сделать, так было бы удобнее. Просто мне выдало  "PDOException
You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances" когда я попробовал сохранить его в сессию

Comment: Как ты уже заметил, что данный объект не сериализуется. Попробуй просто сохранять данные между запросами и в последнем методе этой цепочки уже работай с базой

Comment: Все таки такой способ не самый лучший. В случае с отложенной тразакцией я могу проверить, не вызовут ли эти данные ошибки  при отправки их в базу, при этом ничего не изменяя в ней. И соответственно, если все плохо - отправить ошибку в ответ на запрос. Если передаются только входные данные, то как воспримет их база можно будет узнать только во втором методе... И если есть проблемы, то времени будет потрачено больше. Ладно буду думать